# Tax ID for an international student investing in U.S stocks

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, starting-out-investing, itin

I am an international student studying at Villanova University in Philadelphia, PA. I am very interested in trying my luck at the U.S stock market. However, I do not work on campus and so do not have a Social Security Number. Is there any way around this using which I can trade stocks using an online account?

Comment: Before starting to set up accounts etc, you should take a look at how much money you have available to invest in the stock market. It is harder to make money by buying "odd lots" of shares of any particular stock because the commissions you pay your broker are higher than if you are trading in multiples of 100 shares, and, except for home-run kings, it is generally hard to make money by investing in just a few companies; diversity of investments protects you against the occasional bad investment. As a rule of thumb, _students_ tend not  to have enough money to invest successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You need an [ITIN](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Individual-Taxpayer-Identification-Number-%28ITIN%29). Follow the instructions on the IRS page to apply. You might be better off getting an on-campus employment authorization and getting an SSN, though, as the ITIN process is not really convenient.